# Rearrange side-by side text in a Word doc

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a 2,000+ plus page document that I am formatting to import into an Access database for easier reading.

Only one thing is standing in my way - I have a bunch of items that look like this:

> **Hours:** **Materials:**
>
> 6,708        $1329.00

Everything else in the document is well set up for importing except for that piece.

Looking for way (perhaps some advanced Find and Replace function?) to change that text in the document to read as follows:

> **Hours:** 6,708
>   **Materials:** $1329.00

Thank you for your consideration of my issue.

Comment: Are they all 'Hours' and 'Materials'? That might make it a little easier

Comment: Hi, thank you for your question - yes, it is always Hours and Materials, but there are several that do not have a number figure underneath - they are just blank. In these cases either both elements are blank, or one of the two will have a value underneath.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this wildcard find and replace to find the ones that have data for both Hours and Materials:

[image]

Then you just modify the wildcard to search again for your other possibilities:

- No figure for hours (assume just space?) but $ figure for materials
- Figure for hours but no $ figure for materials
- No figure for either, but just the titles Hours: Materials: